# No ejecutar un ActionResult cuando refresco la pagina

Tags: mvc

¡Saludos! 
Estoy tratando de deshabilitar un controlador cada vez que se refresca la vista.
Es decir, el ActionResult ejecuta una función que inserta datos en sql, pero cada vez que la página se actualiza por f5 o url,el ActionResult se está ejecutando una vez más e inserta una vez más en mi base de datos igual, y esto es un problema.
Agradezco la ayuda de ustedes!

Comment: Creo que hace falta mas información. Considere la posibilidad de incluir el código de la vista. ¿De que forma envía los datos al controller? Especulando un poco: ¿Tal vez pueda incluir un condicional que verifique si ya los datos fueron insertados y en tal caso no lo vuelva a hacer?, ¿Quizas deba limpiar el formulario en la vista, luego de la primera inserción?

Comment: Cuando se presiona F5, el navegador advierte que volverá a enviar la información (es decir, repetirá el POST). Si el usuario hace caso omiso y reenvía de todas maneras, él sabrá lo que hace. Pero si esto perjudica al server por algún motivo, entonces tendrás que efectuar del lado del servidor alguna validación. ¿No rediriges a otra página luego de la acción?